# Tapping temples (on forehead) and worship of Mahaganapaty

Tags: scripture, rituals, ganesha

It is usually believed that tapping [temples on forehead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_(anatomy)) five times with closed fists, accompanied with the recitation of the "Suklambaradharam..." sloka is a shortcut method of worshiping Lord Mahaganapaty.

Since Mahaganapaty is to be worshiped first, many rituals, including Sandhyavandanam, employ this shortcut.

Quoting from [this](http://vishuji.org/sandhya_vandanam.htm) page:

> 2. Vighnesvara Dhyanam Meditation on Lord Vighnesvara
>
> While reciting the following mantra, gently tap the two sides of the
>   forehead with the fists five times with the thought that thereby the
>   nectar (amruta) in the head flows down through all the nerves and
>   invigorates them.
>
> ```
>     Shuklambaradharam Vishnum
>     Sasivarnam Chaturbhujam,
>     Prasannavadanam dhyayeh,
>     Sarva-vighnopasantaye
> ```

[image]

It is believed that the Soma ,as a result of the tapping, flows down from the Sahasrara chakra  to bath Ganapaty who is seated below in the Muladhara Chakra.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bU2RWGmzhv0) is a video demonstrating the the process (move to 2.37 mins).

**Question-Which scriptures mention about this process?**

*Note-I am **only** asking  about the **process** here & not about the sloka "Suklaambaradharam..."*

Comment: This is not actually a nyasa mudra.

Comment: Oh ok , i thought that its a nyasa :)

Comment: @Rickross There is a legend which goes like this: Sage Agastya once arrested the river Kaveri in his kamandalam  which flows between the states of Tamilnadu and Karnataka due to some reason. Due to this, that region was totally filled  with drought. Devatas asked Ganapati for help.  Then Ganesha took the form of a crow and stole agasthya's kamandala while he was meditating. Agasthya realises that the crow was none other than Ganesha. 1/2

Comment: @Rickross He expresses his apologies by tapping his head with his fingers as shown in the figure. Ganesha was then satisfied by his apology and releases water and returns holy pot to agastya. I heard this about leelas of Ganesha. Thus many people now a days too tap their heads and praise Ganesha. It is  said that Ganesha will be satisfy by that act.2/2

Comment: @Sree Charan--You can put this in answer field by citing reference.